# jQuery - How to evaluate two select option values for an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a continue button with the class "options-btn" on a page (it's a multi-step booking process), with two select fields on the page. One of these dropdown select fields needs to have a value selected by the user before they can click the submit button on the page while also disabling the click event?

Each dropdown field has the default select option 0, with the other choice of "1". How can I write a function to basically say "If neither one of these options has a value of 1 selected - alert message "please select an option" and disable the button.

The two ID's associated with these select fields are:

#extra_units_7 & #extra_units_4

This is what I wrote so far, but it's not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".options-btn").click(function() {
  if ( $('#extra_units_7').val() === 0  ||  $('#extra_units_4').val() === 0 )
    alert("Please select an option");
    return false;    
  } else {
      $('.options-btn').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Comment: is a submit button within a form or its just submit button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34825323/4763793 updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-factored your HTML in order to enable you to feedback to the End User without being obtrusive with alert() boxes.

```
<!-- Use ID to attach to in JS -->
<form id="form_units" action="#" method="post">
    <div>
      <!-- Labels, because... well, labels. -->
      <label for="extra_units_4">extra_units_4</label>
      <!-- Use data-attr to identify which elements should be validated and how. This future proofs your code, and it's a good pattern to follow. -->
      <select id="extra_units_4" data-validate="notempty">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    <!-- Hidden element to provide feedback as it's better UX -->
    <div class="fielderror">Please make a selection</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="extra_units_7">extra_units_7</label>
      <select id="extra_units_7" data-validate="notempty">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <div class="fielderror">Please make a selection</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Included an input[type="text"] for fun, and because future proofing is good -->
  <div>
    <label for="extra_units_8">extra_units_8</label>
    <input type="text" id="extra_units_8" data-validate="notempty" />
    <div class="fielderror">Please make a selection</div>
  </div>
  <!-- There appeared to be no reason not to use an input[type="submit"] in your code. Not doing so adds a tiny amount of complexity - so I slimmed the example down. Re-factor yourself for if <button> is a requirement. -->
  <input type="submit" class="options-btn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now we have a simple JS which will capture all `<input>`s with `data-validate="notempty"`.

```
// Make sure you're specific with your selector for your form
$('#form_units').on('submit',function(e) {
  // Hide all .fielderror elements within the context of 'this' form.
  // This means that the next time we submit error messages are reset
  $('.fielderror', this).hide();
  // Select for all 'not empty' validations
  $('[data-validate="notempty"]').each(function (index, item) {

    // Check if it's an input[type="text"] - future proofing your "not empty" requirements. Expand on this idea for "radio" and "checkbox" inputs if and when required.
    if ($(item).attr('type') === 'text') {

      // Text is empty if the length is less than one char
      if ($(item).val().length < 1) {
        // We've found one that is invalid so stop the from from sending
        e.preventDefault();
        // Show the .fielderror text that is associated with the input being validated
        $(item).siblings('.fielderror').show();
      }
    } else {
        // Selects are empty if val() is less than 1. Be warned, this is dependant on having numerical values - and assumes that zero means no answer.
        if ($(item).val() < 1) {
          // We've found one that is invalid so stop the from from sending
          e.preventDefault();
          // Show the .fielderror text that is associated with the input being validated
          $(item).siblings('.fielderror').show();
        }
      }
  })
});
```

Lastly, add a little CSS to hide the error messages and style them when they become shown.

```
.fielderror { display: none; color: red;}
```

jsFiddle of working example with update to HTML structure and text input - https://jsfiddle.net/likestothink/xLLvzps2/9/

Comment: Awesome, it worked! It took me all day to change a few things around but you helped me a ton! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".options-btn").click(function(){
        if ( $('#extra_units_7').val() === 0  &&  $('#extra_units_4').val() === 0 )
            alert("Please select an option");
            return false;    
        }
        return true;
    });
)}
```

You should use && instead of ||. You don't need to trigger click event again.

Comment: Don't use `return false` or `return true`. Use `event.preventDefault()` instead.

Comment: return false includes event.preventDefault():

https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I paste this code into the wordpress theme custom JS editor it throws off this error: http://imgur.com/mLDEaFW            - also the continue button is still clickable

Answer (score 0):

you want to check id the condition is respected at every change of the select an basically disable / enable the button, the code was pretty much ok but you had to perform the check at the change event. I've extracted the check function in an external one just to help redability (you missed a { indenting too much the code) and i've introduced a class on the select to perform the check better, you can use the ID's if you like.

```
<select class="input-select" id="extra_units_4">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
</select>

<select class="input-select" id="extra_units_7">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
</select>

<button class="options-btn" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-select").on( "change", checkSelect);
});

function checkSelect() {
    if ( $('#extra_units_7').val() == '0'  &&  $('#extra_units_4').val() == '0' ) {
    $(".options-btn").attr("disabled","disabled");
        alert("Please select an option");
    }

    else {        
        $(".options-btn").removeAttr('disabled');        }
}
</script>
```

The if contition is an AND because you are checking that both the values are 0 and the check must be performed on string because the select value is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** There is an error for   `});` at the end of your code

**2nd:** use `==` instead of `===`

**3rd:** no need to use `$('.options-btn').trigger('click');`

try this .. if you have submit button without form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".options-btn").on('click',function() {
    if( $('#extra_units_4').val() == 0 ){
      alert("Please select an option in extra_units_4");
      //return false;  
    }else if($('#extra_units_7').val() == 0 ){
      alert("Please select an option in extra_units_7");
        //$('.options-btn').trigger('click');
    }else{
      alert('extra_units_4 value = '+$('#extra_units_4').val());
      alert('extra_units_7 value = '+$('#extra_units_7').val());
    }
  });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xLLvzps2/6/)

or this .. if you have a submit button for a form *(you need to use `e.preventDefault();`  and  `window.location.href` )*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".options-btn").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $('#extra_units_4').val() == 0 ){
      alert("Please select an option in extra_units_4");
      //return false;  
    }else if($('#extra_units_7').val() == 0 ){
      alert("Please select an option in extra_units_7");
        //$('.options-btn').trigger('click');
    }else{
      alert('extra_units_4 value = '+$('#extra_units_4').val());
      alert('extra_units_7 value = '+$('#extra_units_7').val());

      // window.location.href = "type_url_here" // change type_url_here with url you need or with the form action attribute 
    }
  });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xLLvzps2/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach, in case you plan to keep adding selects which are mutually exclusive but required (you would need to add the `required-select` to all of them):
    });

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var hasSelected = function() {
    return $('.required-select option:not([value="0"]):selected').length;
  };

  $('.required-select').change(function() {
    $('.options-btn').prop('disabled', !hasSelected());
  });

  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    if (!hasSelected()) {
      alert("Please select an option");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      alert('submitted');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
  <select id="extra_units_7" class="required-select">
    <option value="0">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <select id="extra_units_4" class="required-select">
    <option value="0">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <button type="submit" class="options-btn" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I think it's overkill to validate on submit when the button is disabled, and it's not intuitive to allow submit, alert error and *then* disable the button. I'd take one of the two approaches in the code above (I prefer specifying in writing that the selects are required and not enabling the submit until they are selected).